# CAGradientLayer only takes up half the screen after rotating to Landscape

Tags: swift, cagradientlayer

A gradient fills the background of my app. I am using the following which works well:

```
gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: dWidth, height: dHeight))
```

However, when I rotate, the gradient only fills half the screen, presumably because rotation makes the frame change

I have tried the following:

```
let deviceScale = UIScreen.main.scale

gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: dWidth*deviceScale, height: dHeight*Scale))
```

Whilst this fixes the rotation problem, I believe it's because the gradient frame is now gigantic. In fact, what I have now is not a gradient, its mostly one plain colour (presumably because the latter colours can't be seen, since the frame is gigantic).

How can I have a gradient which fills the background and works with rotations?

Thanks

---

Update 4th January:

Thanks for the response. This doesn't seem to work for me. I am using a function to set the gradient background:

```
func setGradientBackground(col1: UIColor, col2: UIColor, SPNUM: CGFloat, EPNUM: CGFloat, viewName: String) {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = theView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [col1.cgColor, col2.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: SPNUM, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: EPNUM, y: 1)

    let sublayersCount = view.layer.sublayers?.count ?? 0
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: UInt32(sublayersCount))

    view.layer.layoutSublayers()
    view.bringSubviewToFront(theView)
}
```

The gradientLayer.frame is set within the function as can be seen above

I have tried adding the following, but the gradient does not resize after rotating to landscape:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = theView.bounds
    print("msg1")
```

}

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your gradient layer is set up in a `UIView`, you should override `layoutSubviews`, which is called when the size of the view changes, and set the frame to the desired size there. For example:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews() // make sure to call super first!
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds // fill the view
}
```

If you're setting up the layer in a `UIViewController`, you can override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead (also making sure to call the `super` implementation first).

In general, since you can't use autolayout with layers, you should override one of those methods to do all the layout of your layers.

Comment: I tried utilising layoutSubviews, but the gradient didn't resize after rotation. Please see "Update 4th January" above. Could it be because I am using a function to set the gradient background, and the gradientLayer.frame is set within the function?

Comment: Hmm, in your first code snippet in the update you create a new gradient layer from scratch. What `gradientLayer` property are you referencing in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? I suspect you may not actually have a reference to the gradient layer.

Comment: One more tip - you can use `addSublayer` instead of counting the current layers to add the new layer on top.

Comment: This snippet resizes correctly for me - I create the gradient layer as a property of the view controller so I can reference it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`: https://gist.github.com/kylebshr/ce826ff88b37d1b5499915a8f3caa16a